# Why does odoo wizard fail to open from code and there are no errors?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I have created a wizard in purchase module that checks for attachments.

The process is that if the number of attachments is 0, the `create bill` button should open a wizard asking the user to upload attachments, and if there is attachments, the button should proceed with its usual function of creating a bill.

The problem is that the wizard is not opening and there are no errors.
Here is the function.
Thank you in advance.

```
def action_view_invoice(self):
        if self.attachment_count == 0:
            wiz = self.env.ref(
                'beth_check_attachments.purchase_confirm_attachments')
            view = self.env.ref(
                'beth_check_attachments.purchase_confirm_attachments_form')
       
            return {
                'name': _('Create Bill With No Attachments'),
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'res_model': 'purchase.attachment',
                'views': [(view.id, 'form')],
                'view_id': view.id,
                'nodestroy': True,
                'target': 'new',
                'res_id': wiz.id,
                'context': self.env.context,
            }
        else:
            return super().action_view_invoice()
```

Comment: Turns out the `res_id` was the problem.

Comment: Yes you should create a wizard record and use its ID or just call/return the action without a res_id.

Comment: What do you mean by use its Id?

Comment: `wizard = self.env['purchase.attachment'].create({})` and then use `wizard.id`.